# Authorization Filter Dependency Injection with ASP.New MVC 4 Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement dependency injection on a MVC 4 Web Api Authorization Filter.  I created a FilterProvider that inherits from ActionDescriptorFilterProvider:

```
public class UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider : ActionDescriptorFilterProvider, System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(configuration, actionDescriptor);

        this.BuildUpAttributes(filters);

        return filters;
    }

    private void BuildUpAttributes(IEnumerable filterInfo)
    {
        foreach (FilterInfo filter in filterInfo)
        {
            object o = _container.BuildUp(filter.GetType(), filter);
        }
    }
}
```

and I set this provider to be the default provider in my Global.asax file:

```
var providers = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders().ToList();
        //Remove the default provider
        var defaultprovider = providers.Single(i => i is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Remove(typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), defaultprovider);
        //Add our custom provider
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), new UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider(new UnityContainer()));
```

I also added a dependency in the AuthorizationFilter:

```
public class WebApplicationApiAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{

    [Dependency]
    public IAuthorizationHelper AuthorizationHelper { get; set; }

    #region OnAuthorization
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    //Authorization code, which uses the AuthorizationHelper lives here
}   

}
```

and I set up a mapping in my Unity configuration file:

```
container.RegisterType<WebApplicationApiAuthorizeAttribute>(new InjectionMember[]
            {
                new InjectionProperty("AuthorizationHelper", new ResolvedParameter<IAuthorizationHelper>())
            });

        container.RegisterType<IAuthorizationHelper, WebAuthorizationHelper>(new InjectionMember[]
            {
                new InjectionProperty("Cache", new ResolvedParameter<ICache>(cacheType)),
                new InjectionProperty("UserSessionManager", new ResolvedParameter<IUserSessionManager>()),
                new InjectionProperty("AuthorizationPermissionManager", new ResolvedParameter<IAuthorizationPermissionManager>()),
                new InjectionProperty("ExceptionLogger", new ResolvedParameter<IExceptionLogger>()),
            });
```

I can see that the "BuildUpAttributes" method in the UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider class is executed and that the filter is passed into the _container.BuildUp(...) method, however, the "IAuthorizationHelper" dependency in the WebApplicationApiAuthorizeAttribute does not get resolved.  It is null, when I debug the WebApplicationApiAuthorizeAttribute.

So why is this dependency not being resolved?

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a way to retrieve Filters that are associated at the class level instead of at the method level?  The `GetFilters` method in the `UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider` seems to only act on method level Filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

1. You're building up the `FilterInfo` object instead of its [Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.filterinfo.instance%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

   ```
   foreach (FilterInfo filter in filterInfo)
   {
       object o = _container.BuildUp(filter.GetType(), filter);
   }
   ```

   But this is the correct code:

   ```
   foreach (FilterInfo filter in filterInfo)
   {
       _container.BuildUp(filter.Instance.GetType(), filter.Instance);
   }
   ```
2. Your custom `UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider` gets a new and empty container:

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(
       typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), 
       new UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider(new UnityContainer()));
   ```

   But you should pass on the application's configured container:

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(
       typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), 
       new UnityWebApiFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));
   ```

Comment: I am trying to tackle the same issue and had to change part of yours from _container.BuildUp(filter.GetType(), filter.Instance); to _container.BuildUp(filter.Instance.GetType(), filter.Instance);

Comment: @TimSneed I had to do the same.  Thanks to both of you.